# Entity Framework vs Spring.NET

Tags: .net, data-access-layer

I'm trying to build an e-commerce site. Which technology should I use for the Data Access Layer? What are the pros and cons of each?

I plan on using Silverlight for the Intro and Catalog.

Thanks!

Comment: check out this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(Java) then checkout some of the "See Also" links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework is from Microsoft; Spring is a Java technology, unless you're thinking of Spring.NET.

I'd say either one will work equally well.  Your choice depends on your implementation platform and knowledge of the language and framework.

UPDATE: Now that it's clear that you're interested in Spring.NET, I'd say the deciding factors are features and your eagerness/reluctance to stick with whatever Microsoft gives you.  Spring.NET is not a Microsoft standard.

Comment: I was referring to Spring.NET. I'm leaning more towards the Entity Framework right now because it integrates well with Silverlight. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

They aren't mutually exclusive. Spring lets you inject dependencies and manages the lifecycles of those. Entity Framework is a framework for mapping DAO's to physical tables. For example, using the "Repository" pattern, you build IRepository interface and implement that. Spring then injects that into your service or domain classes